# Response is coming from where?

Tags: servlets

when we submit a form in webpages request will goto servlet which we mention in form action.Servlet will recevie the request by doGet or doPost method. But in doGet or doPost method we have both request and response . where the response is coming from? request we know

Answer (score 0):

Both request and response come from the same place: the container (Tomcat, for example).

When the container receives an HTTP request, it creates an instance of HttpServletRequest, an instance of HttpServletResponse, and pass them both to the servlet's service method.